# Try to send emails but i can't

Tags: php, email, smtp

I can't send emails, i have spent hours with no solution.I tried to search the php.ini file and i found that smtp = localhost and the port = 25.I have included PHPMailerAutoload.php , class.phpmailer.php and class.smtp.php from Github but nothing seems to work.Errors i get are:1) SMTP connect() failed. 2) could not instatiate mail function.

Thanks in advance.

Below is my code:

```
<?php
        session_start();

    require("PHPMailer-master/PHPMailerAutoload.php");
    require("PHPMailer-master/class.phpmailer.php");
    require("PHPMailer-master/class.smtp.php");

    define('PASS', 'secret');

    if(isset($_SESSION['email'])){
        $email = $_SESSION['email'];
    }

    if(isset($_SESSION['company_name'])){
        $comp_name = $_SESSION['company_name'];
    }

    if (isset($_SESSION['endDate'])){
        $endDate = $_SESSION['endDate'];
    }

    if(isset($_SESSION['startDate'])){
        $startDate = $_SESSION['startDate'];
    }

    echo "Company Name " . $comp_name;
    echo "From " . $startDate . " to " . $endDate;

    $from_name="Mario";
    $from = "nikolaou_marios@hotmail.com";
    $to = $email;
    $subject = $comp_name;
    $message = "Start date : " . $startDate . " End Date : " . $endDate;


    $mail = new PHPMailer;
    $mail -> isSMTP();
    $mail -> SMTPAuth = true;

    $mail -> Host = 'localhost';
    $mail -> Username = 'marios.nikolaou87@gmail.com';
    $mail -> Password = 'PASS';
    $mail -> CharSet = 'UTF-8';

    $mail -> SMTPSecure = 'tsl';
    $mail -> Port = 25;

    //$mail -> FromName = $from_name;
    $mail -> setFrom = $from;
    $mail -> addAddress($to);

    $mail -> Subject = $subject;
    $mail -> Body = 'asdasd';

    if(!$mail->Send()){

      echo "Message could not be sent.<br />";
      echo "Mailer error " . $mail -> ErrorInfo;

    }else{

      echo "Message sent.";

    }
?>
```

Comment: Fill in $mail->Host the real hostname (most likely your domain) or use one the smtp feature of these mail services (e.g. gmail).

Comment: i tried 127.0.0.1 as host but nothing

Comment: The holy spirit will give me the solution when i sleep. :D

Comment: 127.0.0.1 is not the real hostname. 127.0.0.1 refers to localhost, ergo the machine itself.